# Creating custom archive and single listing views in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have downloaded and installed [Easy Property Listings](https://easypropertylistings.com.au/) plugin for wordpress, and have followed the instructions on modifying the code to work with my (custom made) theme.

I want to display property listings and individual properties on my own custom pages (from handcrafted PHP/HTML/CSS etc). In order to do so, I need to know how I can access the following artefacts in my PHP code:

1. The collection object that holds the list of properties, (so I can
   iterate over the items in the collection)
2. The property object and its associated fields, so I may be able to access and display the relevant fields in my page.

A similar question has been asked on the [FAQ](http://codex.easypropertylistings.com.au/article/100-we-want-to-display-less-or-more-info-on-the-archive-and-single-listing-views-how-can-we-create-a-unique-look) page, but the "answer" there - besides confirming that this is possible, does not provide any detail.

Can someone provide some help on how to directly access these objects in my custom pages, so that I can display the required information on my pages?

Comment: Does the plugin uses short codes to display data on pages??

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai: Yes it does. I'm pretty new to wordpress, but I am an experienced PHP coder, so would prefer to be able to write pages that access the 'property' objects directly in my pages, so I have fine control of what is actually displayed in my pages.

Comment: Take a look at this link..It might be worth looking at..Also there is a video for better explanation : http://codex.easypropertylistings.com.au/article/121-how-to-create-your-own-custom-theme-templates-or-modify-existing-ones-using-the-theme-template-loader